# Why my code-style Eclipse is different other developer

Tags: java, eclipse, format

- We are user codeStyle **"Java Conventions[built in]"** in our project.
- I'm already export and import  codeStyle of the my friend programmer,
- But not solved see the difference in image.
- Line green is different, see image.
- We make simonized always has difference alignment vertical space.

[image: Same code style generator different result]

- My computer has Windows 8.1 others 10,
- We are use Eclipse "JBoss Developer Studio"
- Version  9.0.0.GA

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the 'Displayed tab width' preference which is not part of the formatter settings.

This is configured in the Preferences on the 'General > Editors > Text Editors' page.

Comment: I additionally recommend that your team enables the "Insert spaces for tabs" option on the same page. So you can use TAB while editing, but eclipse replaces each tab by spaces when saving the file. Doing like this, all the source file will look always the same, regardeless in which editor you open it.